# select radio buttons using vba

Tags: vba, web, web-scraping, radio-button

```
Sub Mind_stone()
Dim IE As Object
Dim doa As HTMLDocument
Dim HTMLdoc As HTMLDocument
Dim button As HTMLInputButtonElement
Dim i As Integer
Set IE = CreateObject("internetexplorer.application")

IE.Visible = True
IE.navigate "https://eqvm.titusn.co.in/PavbnjsPnrtl/login.jsp"

Do While IE.busy
 Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop
IE.document.getElementById("username").Value = "efeqwf"
IE.document.getElementById("password").Value = "*****"
IE.document.getElementsByClassName("button ok")(0).Click
IE.document.querySelector("[title='PSR - Indirect Materials']").Click
'IE.document.getElementsByClassName("dijitReset dojoxMultiSelectItem")(1).Click
'IE.document.querySelector("[title='div_3_1_2_radiogroup']").Click
'itemlength = IE.document.all.Item("div_3_1_2_radiogroup").Length
'IE.document.getElementsByName("div_3_1_2_radiogroup").Item(1).Checked = True
End Sub
```

```html
<div class="dijitReset dojoxMultiSelectItem BPMMultiSelectFocused dojoxCheckedMultiSelectSelectedOption" id="dojox_form__CheckedMultiSelectItem_7" widgetid="dojox_form__CheckedMultiSelectItem_7" aria-selected="true">
    <div class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dojoxMultiSelectItemBox dijitRadio dijitRadioChecked dijitChecked" role="presentation" widgetid="dijit_form_CheckBox_7">
        <input
            type="radio"
            class="dijitReset dijitCheckBoxInput"
            data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode"
            data-
            <div
            class="dijit dijitReset dijitInline dojoxMultiSelectItemBox dijitRadio dijitRadioChecked dijitChecked"
            role="presentation"
            widgetid="dijit_form_CheckBox_7"
        />
        <input
            type="radio"
            class="dijitReset dijitCheckBoxInput"
            data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode"
            data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:_onClick"
            value="on"
            tabindex="0"
            id="dijit_form_CheckBox_7"
            aria-labelledby=" dijit_form_CheckBox_7_radio_label"
            name="div_3_1_2_radiogroup"
            aria-checked="true"
            style="user-select: none;"
        />
    </div>

    <input
        type="radio"
        class="dijitReset dijitCheckBoxInput"
        data-dojo-attach-point="focusNode"
        data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:_onClick"
        value="on"
        tabindex="0"
        id="dijit_form_CheckBox_7"
        aria-labelledby=" dijit_form_CheckBox_7_radio_label"
        name="div_3_1_2_radiogroup"
        aria-checked="true"
        style="user-select: none;"
    />
    <div class="dijitInline dojoxMultiSelectItemLabel" data-dojo-attach-point="labelNode" data-dojo-attach-event="onclick:_onClick" id="dijit_form_CheckBox_7_radio_label">Create New / Create from existing PSR</div>
</div>
```

i am new to the web-**scraping** , now i am trying to click the radio button through vba but i cant find the solution to that

for the first 4 stage (username,password,button ok,title) i have successfully passed but i am struggling for the above code

[Second one is which i'am trying to click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fh98K.png)

Comment: FYI it’s __scraping__ not scrapping. ‘Scrapping’ means throwing away like rubbish :-(

Comment: Thanks for improving my english,any idea for help on this ?